# C# and Excel advanced filter

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to filter data from one workbook to another obne, but I get an unpsecified exception.

I can't find many examples for adavnced filtering in excel using c# and I don't know Where's exactly my error.

Here's my code:

```
public void excel()
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookImport;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookOriginal;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetImport;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetOriginal;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBookImport = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:/open.xls");
        xlWorkBookOriginal = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:/open1.xls");
        xlWorkBookOriginal.Activate();
        xlWorkSheetOriginal = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBookOriginal.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheetOriginal.get_Range("1:7").Delete();
        xlWorkBookImport.Activate();
        xlWorkSheetImport = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBookImport.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheetOriginal.Cells.AdvancedFilter(Excel.XlFilterAction.xlFilterCopy, Type.Missing, CopyToRange: "a1:a6", Unique: true);

        xlApp.Visible = true;
    }
```

Anyone can help me with a solution?

Comment: What is the exception you get? I don't quite understand what "filter" do you mean. But i think at least you can read all data from one workbook and filter them in C# by LINQ and the populate them in the second workbook

Comment: Hi, the exception wasn't specified. Excel has an "advanced filter" tool which allows to filter data if the origin and the target have the same exact heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out myeslf in the end:

```
public void excel()
{         
Excel.Application xlApp;         
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookImport;         
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookOriginal;         
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetImport;         
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetOriginal;          
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();         
xlWorkBookImport = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:/open.xls");         
xlWorkBookOriginal = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:/open1.xls");             
xlWorkBookOriginal.Activate();         
xlWorkSheetOriginal = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBookOriginal.Worksheets.get_Item(1);         
xlWorkSheetOriginal.get_Range("1:7").Delete(); 
// added code
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheetOriginal.get_Range("a1:v53");  
//  
xlWorkBookImport.Activate(); 
xlWorkSheetImport = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBookImport.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
// added code
xlWorkSheetImport.Activate();
Excel.Range target = xlWorkSheetImport.get_Range("a1:f1"); 
//
// modified code            
xlWorkSheetOriginal.Cells.AdvancedFilter(Action : Excel.XlFilterAction.xlFilterCopy, 
CriteriaRange: Type.Missing, CopyToRange: target, Unique: false);
//          
xlApp.Visible = true;     
}
```